# Ubuntu: setting up email server with multiple domains

Tags: ubuntu, email-server

I have a website setup on server-A, which is a shared hosting. I would like to host my emails on different server lets say on server-B (Digital ocean VPS) due to space issues.

I have checked different tutorials online, but failed to create a scenario of mine. I want server-B to be an email server, I can install, postfix, dovecot, squirrelmail, lamp stack. But I am confusing around the configurations.

I have already setup website xyz.com on server-A, I want server-B to be used as mail server. What I need here is I want to update mx entries on server-A so that it points to server-B.

What is the process and type of configuration needed to solve this kind of environment?

**UPDATE:**

I have set up my VPS (Server-B) for mail server and it's working fine. 
I am still newbie in mail server configurations.

Here what I have done:-

1. Created an "A Record" in DNS say, "mailbox.mymailservice.com" that points to my VPS IP.
2. Installed and configured my VPS (Ubuntu 16.04 x64) for LAMP stack, postfix, dovecot, squirrelmail with domain name "mailbox.mymailservice.com".
3. I have added new users such as user1, and I am being able to send and receive emails with an email user1@mailbox.mymailservice.com, which is fine.

But the core requirement here is to how to host another domains emails in this vps so that I can used it as a mail service provider. Lets say I have a client whose domain name is myclient1.com, they just needs to point their mx entries to my mailbox.mymailservice.com so that they can host their email in my server. What additional configurations and services are required to do this kind of scenarion?

Comment: This sounds like you might just need to read up on MX (and maybe SPF) records - if you have tried doing this already, and are having issues, could you update your question to mention [what you have tried, and what your issue right now is](https://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask)?

Comment: @iwaseatenbyagrue i have updated my question.

Comment: I have this problem, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to set up an MX record, pointing mails for `example.com` to `example.org`. In BIND style:

```
example.com     MX   10 example.org.
```

Of course, you won't set up the MX records on "Server-A", but on your DNS server (which hopefully is different), and `example.org` must point to your "Server-B".